# Qt: Debugger Crashes in qscopedpointer.h (application works though)

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, crash, qscopedpointer

After recently converting my project over to make use Qt's opengl support (and thus using the Qt 5.4.0 MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit Kit), I've been unable to properly debug because my application always 'crashes' at line 134 of qscopedpointer.h.

I can run in debug or release mode perfectly fine, but actually *debugging* leads to this crash. This issue also never manifested before switching over to this kit and using QGLWidget.

I have no idea how to deal with this problem. The Disassembler shows me this:

```
        Qt5Guid!QScopedPointer<QObjectData,QScopedPointerDeleter<QObjectData> >::data [c:\work\build\qt5_workdir\w\s\qtbase\src\corelib\tools\qscopedpointer.h @ 134]:
0x7fee2d5a2f0                    mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx
0x7fee2d5a2f5  <+0x0005>         mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+8]
0x7fee2d5a2fa  <+0x000a>         mov     rax,qword ptr [rax]
```

where the fourth line is unable to run.

Stacktrace:

```
c:\work\build\qt5_workdir\w\s\qtbase\src\corelib\tools\qscopedpointer.h:135: error: Exception at 0x7fee2d5a2fa, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)
```

Nowhere in my application do I make any direct calls to qscopedpointer, so I have no clue what the issue is.

Does anyone have any advice? I may not need the debugger right now, but I can guarantee I will need it in the future.

Not only is my code immense, but  I can't think of any relevant chunks to post, since the debugger doesn't crash on any of **my** lines.

**Edit:** If try to resume debugging when the debugger reaches this line, it sometimes continues.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Stepping in debugger causes threads to run differently and may make defects to manifest themselves.

Comment: I have similar problem inside `QWindowsContext::findPlatformWindow` after migration on Qt 5.4 (sometimes even without debugger). Do you have any progress in analysis of it?

Comment: @Ilya I recall being able to circumvent my problem by starting my application normally, and then attaching the debugger a short while afterwards, OR trying to force the debugger to continue despite getting the errors. The problem seems to have disappeared on its own over time, however I wasn't able to pinpoint the reason why.

Comment: @Yattabyte, thank you for this information!